# Writing cojoin or cobind for n-dimensional grid type

Tags: haskell, comonad

Using the typical definition of type-level naturals, I've defined an n-dimensional grid.

```
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

data Nat = Z | S Nat

data U (n :: Nat) x where
  Point :: x -> U Z x
  Dimension :: [U n x] -> U n x -> [U n x] -> U (S n) x

dmap :: (U n x -> U m r) -> U (S n) x -> U (S m) r
dmap f (Dimension ls mid rs) = Dimension (map f ls) (f mid) (map f rs)

instance Functor (U n) where
  fmap f (Point x) = Point (f x)
  fmap f d@Dimension{} = dmap (fmap f) d
```

Now I want to make it an instance of Comonad, but I can't quite wrap my brain around it.

```
class Functor w => Comonad w where
  (=>>)    :: w a -> (w a -> b) -> w b
  coreturn :: w a -> a
  cojoin   :: w a -> w (w a)

  x =>> f = fmap f (cojoin x)
  cojoin xx = xx =>> id

instance Comonad (U n) where
  coreturn (Point x) = x
  coreturn (Dimension _ mid _) = coreturn mid

  -- cojoin :: U Z x -> U Z (U Z x)
  cojoin (Point x) = Point (Point x)
  -- cojoin ::U (S n) x -> U (S n) (U (S n) x)
  cojoin d@Dimension{} = undefined

  -- =>> :: U Z x -> (U Z x -> r) -> U Z r
  p@Point{} =>> f = Point (f p)
  -- =>> :: U (S n) x -> (U (S n) x -> r) -> U (S n) r
  d@Dimension{} =>> f = undefined
```

Using `cojoin` on an n-dimensional grid will produce an n-dimensional grid of n-dimensional grids. I'd like to provide an instance with the same idea as [this one](http://hpaste.org/76465), which is that the *value* of the *cojoined* grid at (x,y,z) should be the *original* grid *focused* on (x,y,z). To adapt that code, it appears that we need to reify `n` in order to perform `n` "fmaps" and `n` "rolls". You don't have to do it that way but if that helps, then there you go.

Comment: Comonads m, n compose if there's a suitable "distributive law" of type forall x. m (n x) -> n (m x). Looks to me like you're iteratively composing the element-between-left-list-and-right-list comonad whose distributive law (modulo unenforced rectangularity constraints) is transposition. So you might be able to crunch this one step at a time. (Apparently trivial lifesaving tip: use snoc-lists for left-of-the-cursor, so you keep orientation clear in your code.)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

**Jagger/Richards: you can't always get what you want, but if you try sometime you just might find that you get what you need.**

### Cursors in Lists

Let me rebuild the components of your structure using snoc- and cons-lists to keep the spatial properties clear. I define

```
data Bwd x = B0 | Bwd x :< x deriving (Functor, Foldable, Traversable, Show)
data Fwd x = F0 | x :> Fwd x deriving (Functor, Foldable, Traversable, Show)
infixl 5 :<
infixr 5 :>

data Cursor x = Cur (Bwd x) x (Fwd x) deriving (Functor, Foldable, Traversable, Show)
```

Let's have comonads

```
class Functor f => Comonad f where
  counit  :: f x -> x
  cojoin  :: f x -> f (f x)
```

and let's make sure cursors are comonads

```
instance Comonad Cursor where
  counit (Cur _ x _) = x
  cojoin c = Cur (lefts c) c (rights c) where
    lefts (Cur B0 _ _) = B0
    lefts (Cur (xz :< x) y ys) = lefts c :< c where c = Cur xz x (y :> ys)
    rights (Cur _ _ F0) = F0
    rights (Cur xz x (y :> ys)) = c :> rights c where c = Cur (xz :< x) y ys
```

If you're turned on to this kind of stuff, you'll note that `Cursor` is a spatially pleasing variant of `InContext []`

```
InContext f x = (x, ∂f x)
```

where ∂ takes the formal derivative of a functor, giving its notion of one-hole context. `InContext f` is always a `Comonad`, as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12872133/828361), and what we have here is just that `Comonad` induced by the differential structure, where `counit` extracts the element at the focus and `cojoin` decorates each element with its own context, effectively giving you a context full of refocused cursors and with an unmoved cursor at its focus. Let's have an example.

```
> cojoin (Cur (B0 :< 1) 2 (3 :> 4 :> F0))
Cur (B0 :< Cur B0 1 (2 :> 3 :> 4 :> F0))
    (Cur (B0 :< 1) 2 (3 :> 4 :> F0))
    (  Cur (B0 :< 1 :< 2) 3 (4 :> F0)
    :> Cur (B0 :< 1 :< 2 :< 3) 4 F0
    :> F0)
```

See? The 2 in focus has been decorated to become the cursor-at-2; to the left, we have the list of the cursor-at-1; to the right, the list of the cursor-at-3 and the cursor-at-4.

### Composing Cursors, Transposing Cursors?

Now, the structure you're asking to be a `Comonad` is the n-fold composition of `Cursor`. Let's have

```
newtype (:.:) f g x = C {unC :: f (g x)} deriving Show
```

To persuade comonads `f` and `g` to compose, the `counit`s compose neatly, but you need a "distributive law"

```
transpose :: f (g x) -> g (f x)
```

so you can make the composite `cojoin` like this

```
f (g x)
  -(fmap cojoin)->
f (g (g x))
  -cojoin->
f (f (g (g x)))
  -(fmap transpose)->
f (g (f (g x)))
```

What laws should `transpose` satisfy? Probably something like

```
counit . transpose = fmap counit
cojoin . transpose = fmap transpose . transpose . fmap cojoin
```

or whatever it takes to ensure that any two ways to shoogle some sequence of f's and g's from one order to another give the same result.

Can we define a `transpose` for `Cursor` with itself? One way to get some sort of transposition cheaply is to note that `Bwd` and `Fwd` are *zippily* applicative, hence so is `Cursor`.

```
instance Applicative Bwd where
  pure x = pure x :< x
  (fz :< f) <*> (sz :< s) = (fz <*> sz) :< f s
  _ <*> _ = B0

instance Applicative Fwd where
  pure x = x :> pure x
  (f :> fs) <*> (s :> ss) = f s :> (fs <*> ss)
  _ <*> _ = F0

instance Applicative Cursor where
  pure x = Cur (pure x) x (pure x)
  Cur fz f fs <*> Cur sz s ss = Cur (fz <*> sz) (f s) (fs <*> ss)
```

And here you should begin to smell the rat. Shape mismatch results in *truncation*, and that's going to break the obviously desirable property that self-transpose is self-inverse. Any kind of raggedness will not survive. We do get a transposition operator: `sequenceA`, and for completely regular data, all is bright and beautiful.

```
> regularMatrixCursor
Cur (B0 :< Cur (B0 :< 1) 2 (3 :> F0))
          (Cur (B0 :< 4) 5 (6 :> F0))
          (Cur (B0 :< 7) 8 (9 :> F0) :> F0)
> sequenceA regularMatrixCursor
Cur (B0 :< Cur (B0 :< 1) 4 (7 :> F0))
          (Cur (B0 :< 2) 5 (8 :> F0))
          (Cur (B0 :< 3) 6 (9 :> F0) :> F0)
```

But even if I just move one of the inner cursors out of alignment (never mind making the sizes ragged), things go awry.

```
> raggedyMatrixCursor
Cur (B0 :< Cur ((B0 :< 1) :< 2) 3 F0)
          (Cur (B0 :< 4) 5 (6 :> F0))
          (Cur (B0 :< 7) 8 (9 :> F0) :> F0)
> sequenceA raggedyMatrixCursor
Cur (B0 :< Cur (B0 :< 2) 4 (7 :> F0))
          (Cur (B0 :< 3) 5 (8 :> F0))
          F0
```

When you have one outer cursor position and multiple inner cursor positions, there's no transposition which is going to behave well. Self-composing `Cursor` allows the inner structures to be ragged relative to one another, so no `transpose`, no `cojoin`. You can, and I did, define

```
instance (Comonad f, Traversable f, Comonad g, Applicative g) =>
  Comonad (f :.: g) where
    counit = counit . counit . unC
    cojoin = C . fmap (fmap C . sequenceA) . cojoin . fmap cojoin . unC
```

but it's an onus on us to make sure we keep the inner structures regular. If you're willing to accept that burden, then you can iterate, because `Applicative` and `Traversable` are readily closed under composition. Here are the bits and pieces

```
instance (Functor f, Functor g) => Functor (f :.: g) where
  fmap h (C fgx) = C (fmap (fmap h) fgx)

instance (Applicative f, Applicative g) => Applicative (f :.: g) where
  pure = C . pure . pure
  C f <*> C s = C (pure (<*>) <*> f <*> s)

instance (Functor f, Foldable f, Foldable g) => Foldable (f :.: g) where
  fold = fold . fmap fold . unC

instance (Traversable f, Traversable g) => Traversable (f :.: g) where
  traverse h (C fgx) = C <$> traverse (traverse h) fgx
```

**Edit:** for completeness, here's what it does when all is regular,

```
> cojoin (C regularMatrixCursor)
C {unC = Cur (B0 :< Cur (B0 :<
  C {unC = Cur B0 (Cur B0 1 (2 :> (3 :> F0))) (Cur B0 4 (5 :> (6 :> F0)) :> (Cur B0 7 (8 :> (9 :> F0)) :> F0))}) 
 (C {unC = Cur B0 (Cur (B0 :< 1) 2 (3 :> F0)) (Cur (B0 :< 4) 5 (6 :> F0) :> (Cur (B0 :< 7) 8 (9 :> F0) :> F0))})
 (C {unC = Cur B0 (Cur ((B0 :< 1) :< 2) 3 F0) (Cur ((B0 :< 4) :< 5) 6 F0 :> (Cur ((B0 :< 7) :< 8) 9 F0 :> F0))} :> F0))
(Cur (B0 :<
  C {unC = Cur (B0 :< Cur B0 1 (2 :> (3 :> F0))) (Cur B0 4 (5 :> (6 :> F0))) (Cur B0 7 (8 :> (9 :> F0)) :> F0)})
 (C {unC = Cur (B0 :< Cur (B0 :< 1) 2 (3 :> F0)) (Cur (B0 :< 4) 5 (6 :> F0)) (Cur (B0 :< 7) 8 (9 :> F0) :> F0)}) 
 (C {unC = Cur (B0 :< Cur ((B0 :< 1) :< 2) 3 F0) (Cur ((B0 :< 4) :< 5) 6 F0) (Cur ((B0 :< 7) :< 8) 9 F0 :> F0)} :> F0))
(Cur (B0 :<
  C {unC = Cur ((B0 :< Cur B0 1 (2 :> (3 :> F0))) :< Cur B0 4 (5 :> (6 :> F0))) (Cur B0 7 (8 :> (9 :> F0))) F0})
 (C {unC = Cur ((B0 :< Cur (B0 :< 1) 2 (3 :> F0)) :< Cur (B0 :< 4) 5 (6 :> F0)) (Cur (B0 :< 7) 8 (9 :> F0)) F0})
 (C {unC = Cur ((B0 :< Cur ((B0 :< 1) :< 2) 3 F0) :< Cur ((B0 :< 4) :< 5) 6 F0) (Cur ((B0 :< 7) :< 8) 9 F0) F0} :> F0)
:> F0)}
```

### Hancock's Tensor Product

For regularity, you need something stronger than composition. You need to be able to capture the notion of "an f-structure of g-structures-all-the-same-shape". This is what the inestimable Peter Hancock calls the "tensor product", which I'll write `f :><: g`: there's one "outer" f-shape and one "inner" g-shape common to all the inner g-structures, so transposition is readily definable and always self-inverse. Hancock's tensor is not conveniently definable in Haskell, but in a dependently typed setting, it's easy to formulate a notion of "container" which has this tensor.

To give you the idea, consider a degenerate notion of container

```
data (:<|) s p x = s :<| (p -> x)
```

where we say `s` is the type of "shapes" and `p` the type of "positions". A value consists of the choice of a shape and the storage of an `x` in each position. In the dependent case, the type of positions may depend on the choice of the shape (e.g., for lists, the shape is a number (the length), and you have that many positions). These containers have a tensor product

```
(s :<| p) :><: (s' :<| p')  =  (s, s') :<| (p, p')
```

which is like a generalised matrix: a pair of shapes give the dimensions, and then you have an element at each pair of positions. You can do this perfectly well when types `p` and `p'` depend on values in `s` and `s'`, and that is exactly Hancock's definition of the tensor product of containers.

### InContext for Tensor Products

Now, as you may have learned in high school, `∂(s :<| p) = (s, p) :<| (p-1)` where `p-1` is some type with one fewer element than `p`. Like ∂(s*x^p) = (s*p)*x^(p-1). You select one position (recording it in the shape) and delete it. The snag is that `p-1` is tricky to get your hands on without dependent types. But `InContext` selects a position *without deleting it*.

```
InContext (s :<| p) ~= (s, p) :<| p
```

This works just as well for the dependent case, and we joyously acquire

```
InContext (f :><: g) ~= InContext f :><: InContext g
```

Now we know that `InContext f` is always a `Comonad`, and this tells us that tensor products of `InContext`s are comonadic because they are themselves `InContext`s. That's to say, you pick one position per dimension (and that gives you exactly one position in the whole thing), where before we had one outer position and lots of inner positions. With the tensor product replacing composition, everything works sweetly.

### Naperian Functors

But there is a subclass of `Functor` for which the tensor product and the composition coincide. These are the `Functor`s `f` for which `f () ~ ()`: i.e., there is only one shape anyway, so raggedy values in compositions are ruled out in the first place. These `Functor`s are all isomorphic to `(p ->)` for some position set `p` which we can think of as the *logarithm* (the exponent to which `x` must be raised to give `f x`). Correspondingly, Hancock calls these `Naperian` functors after John Napier (whose ghost haunts the part of Edinburgh where Hancock lives).

```
class Applicative f => Naperian f where
  type Log f
  project :: f x -> Log f -> x
  positions :: f (Log f)
  --- project positions = id
```

A `Naperian` functor has a logarithm, inducing a `project`ion function mapping positions to the elements found there. `Naperian` functors are all zippily `Applicative`, with `pure` and `<*>` corresponding to the K and S combinators for the projections. It's also possible to construct a value where at each position is stored that very position's representation. Laws of logarithms which you might remember pop up pleasingly.

```
newtype Id x = Id {unId :: x} deriving Show

instance Naperian Id where
  type Log Id = ()
  project (Id x) () = x
  positions = Id ()

newtype (:*:) f g x = Pr (f x, g x) deriving Show

instance (Naperian f, Naperian g) => Naperian (f :*: g) where
  type Log (f :*: g) = Either (Log f) (Log g)
  project (Pr (fx, gx)) (Left p) = project fx p
  project (Pr (fx, gx)) (Right p) = project gx p
  positions = Pr (fmap Left positions, fmap Right positions)
```

Note that a fixed size array (a *vector*) is given by `(Id :*: Id :*: ... :*: Id :*: One)`, where `One` is the constant unit functor, whose logarithm is `Void`. So an array is `Naperian`. Now, we also have

```
instance (Naperian f, Naperian g) => Naperian (f :.: g) where
  type Log (f :.: g) = (Log f, Log g)
  project (C fgx) (p, q) = project (project fgx p) q
  positions = C $ fmap (\ p -> fmap (p ,) positions) positions
```

which means that multi-dimensional arrays are `Naperian`.

To construct a version of `InContext f` for `Naperian f`, just point to a position!

```
data Focused f x = f x :@ Log f

instance Functor f => Functor (Focused f) where
  fmap h (fx :@ p) = fmap h fx :@ p

instance Naperian f => Comonad (Focused f) where
  counit (fx :@ p) = project fx p
  cojoin (fx :@ p) = fmap (fx :@) positions :@ p
```

So, in particular, a `Focused` n-dimensional array will indeed be a comonad. A composition of vectors is a tensor product of n vectors, because vectors are `Naperian`. But the `Focused` n-dimensional array will be the n-fold tensor product, *not the composition*, of the n `Focused` vectors which determine its dimensions. To express this comonad in terms of zippers, we'll need to express them in a form which makes it possible to construct the tensor product. I'll leave that as an exercise for the future.

Comment: Naperian functors are also called representable functors: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/representable-functors/3.0.0.1/doc/html/Data-Functor-Representable.html

Comment: That's the stuff, yes. I see it's standard terminology, so I probably can't insist. But I do think that Hancock's "Naperian" puts rather more of a finger on it. Sometime in 2000 or 2001 that I was standing at his whiteboard when he poured me a Scotch and said "Now, you be Leibniz and I'll be Napier!". We scribbled away, trying to figure out what the hell was going on. So much structure has emerged since, but Haskell's type system is often not dependent enough to bottle it nicely.

Answer (score 12):

One more try, inspired by pigworkers post and http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/representable-functors/3.0.0.1/doc/html/Data-Functor-Representable.html.

A representable (or Naperian) functor is a comonad itself, if the key (or log) is a monoid! Then `coreturn` gets the value at position `mempty`. And `cojoin` `mappend`s the two keys it has available. (Just as the comonad instance for `(p ->)`.)

```
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

import Data.List (genericIndex)
import Data.Monoid
import Data.Key
import Data.Functor.Representable

data Nat = Z | S Nat

data U (n :: Nat) x where
  Point :: x -> U Z x
  Dimension :: [U n x] -> U n x -> [U n x] -> U (S n) x

dmap :: (U n x -> U m r) -> U (S n) x -> U (S m) r
dmap f (Dimension ls mid rs) = Dimension (map f ls) (f mid) (map f rs)

instance Functor (U n) where
  fmap f (Point x) = Point (f x)
  fmap f d@Dimension{} = dmap (fmap f) d

class Functor w => Comonad w where
  (=>>)    :: w a -> (w a -> b) -> w b
  coreturn :: w a -> a
  cojoin   :: w a -> w (w a)

  x =>> f = fmap f (cojoin x)
  cojoin xx = xx =>> id
```

`U` is representable if the lists are infinitely long. Then there's only one shape. The key of `U n` is a vector of n integers.

```
type instance Key (U n) = UKey n

data UKey (n :: Nat) where
  P :: UKey Z
  D :: Integer -> UKey n -> UKey (S n)

instance Lookup (U n) where lookup = lookupDefault
instance Indexable (U n) where
  index (Point x) P = x
  index (Dimension ls mid rs) (D i k) 
    | i < 0 = index (ls `genericIndex` (-i - 1)) k
    | i > 0 = index (rs `genericIndex` ( i - 1)) k
    | otherwise = index mid k
```

We need to split the `Representable` instance up in two cases, one for `Z` and one for `S`, because we don't have a value of type `U n` to pattern match on.

```
instance Representable (U Z) where
  tabulate f = Point (f P)
instance Representable (U n) => Representable (U (S n)) where
  tabulate f = Dimension 
    (map (\i -> tabulate (f . D (-i))) [1..]) 
    (tabulate (f . D 0))
    (map (\i -> tabulate (f . D   i)) [1..])

instance Monoid (UKey Z) where
  mempty = P
  mappend P P = P
instance Monoid (UKey n) => Monoid (UKey (S n)) where
  mempty = D 0 mempty
  mappend (D il kl) (D ir kr) = D (il + ir) (mappend kl kr)
```

And the key of `U n` is indeed a monoid, so we can turn `U n` into a comonad, using the default implementations from the representable-functor package.

```
instance (Monoid (UKey n), Representable (U n)) => Comonad (U n) where
  coreturn = extractRep
  cojoin = duplicateRep
  (=>>) = flip extendRep
```

This time I did some testing.

```
testVal :: U (S (S Z)) Int
testVal = Dimension 
  (repeat (Dimension (repeat (Point 1)) (Point 2) (repeat (Point 3))))
          (Dimension (repeat (Point 4)) (Point 5) (repeat (Point 6)))
  (repeat (Dimension (repeat (Point 7)) (Point 8) (repeat (Point 9))))

-- Hacky Eq instance, just for testing
instance Eq x => Eq (U n x) where
  Point a == Point b = a == b
  Dimension la a ra == Dimension lb b rb = take 3 la == take 3 lb && a == b && take 3 ra == take 3 rb

instance Show x => Show (U n x) where
  show (Point x) = "(Point " ++ show x ++ ")"
  show (Dimension l a r) = "(Dimension " ++ show (take 2 l) ++ " " ++ show a ++ " " ++ show (take 2 r) ++ ")"

test = 
  coreturn (cojoin testVal) == testVal && 
  fmap coreturn (cojoin testVal) == testVal && 
  cojoin (cojoin testVal) == fmap cojoin (cojoin testVal)
```

Answer (score 2):

So this turns out to be wrong. I'll leave it here in case anybody wants to try to fix it.

This implementation is the way @pigworker suggested I think. It compiles, but I haven't tested it. (I took the `cojoin1` implementation from http://blog.sigfpe.com/2006/12/evaluating-cellular-automata-is.html)

```
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

data Nat = Z | S Nat

data U (n :: Nat) x where
  Point :: x -> U Z x
  Dimension :: [U n x] -> U n x -> [U n x] -> U (S n) x

unPoint :: U Z x -> x
unPoint (Point x) = x

dmap :: (U n x -> U m r) -> U (S n) x -> U (S m) r
dmap f (Dimension ls mid rs) = Dimension (map f ls) (f mid) (map f rs)

right, left :: U (S n) x -> U (S n) x
right (Dimension a b (c:cs)) = Dimension (b:a) c cs
left  (Dimension (a:as) b c) = Dimension as a (b:c)

instance Functor (U n) where
  fmap f (Point x) = Point (f x)
  fmap f d@Dimension{} = dmap (fmap f) d

class Functor w => Comonad w where
  (=>>)    :: w a -> (w a -> b) -> w b
  coreturn :: w a -> a
  cojoin   :: w a -> w (w a)

  x =>> f = fmap f (cojoin x)
  cojoin xx = xx =>> id

instance Comonad (U n) where
  coreturn (Point x) = x
  coreturn (Dimension _ mid _) = coreturn mid
  cojoin (Point x) = Point (Point x)
  cojoin d@Dimension{} = fmap unlayer . unlayer . fmap dist . cojoin1 . fmap cojoin . layer $ d

dist :: U (S Z) (U n x) -> U n (U (S Z) x)
dist = layerUnder . unlayer

layerUnder :: U (S n) x -> U n (U (S Z) x)
layerUnder d@(Dimension _ Point{} _) = Point d
layerUnder d@(Dimension _ Dimension{} _) = dmap layerUnder d

unlayer :: U (S Z) (U n x) -> U (S n) x
unlayer = dmap unPoint

layer :: U (S n) x -> U (S Z) (U n x)
layer = dmap Point

cojoin1 :: U (S Z) x -> U (S Z) (U (S Z) x)
cojoin1 a = layer $ Dimension (tail $ iterate left a) a (tail $ iterate right a)
```

Comment: Your solution is picking the grid apart. With some modifications (using `unfoldr` instead of `iterate`, and Maybe-fying `left` and `right`), you can see that the points in the n-dimensional grid returned by `cojoin` consist of rolled "rows" (in case of a 2-dimensional grid). I might be misunderstanding the problem, but this doesn't look like the intended functionality of this comonad.

Comment: @Tinctorius hmm, indeed. After reading what pigworker said I think I miss the transposition step.