# Comonadically finding all the ways to focus on a grid

Tags: haskell, zipper, comonad

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFoldable #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveTraversable #-}
import Control.Comonad
import Data.Functor.Reverse
import Data.List (unfoldr)
```

First some context (ha ha). I have a [zipper](https://www.st.cs.uni-saarland.de/edu/seminare/2005/advanced-fp/docs/huet-zipper.pdf) over non-empty lists.

```
data LZipper a = LZipper (Reverse [] a) a [a]
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Read, Functor, Foldable, Traversable)

mkZipper :: a -> [a] -> LZipper a
mkZipper = LZipper (Reverse [])
```

You can step in either direction along the zipper, but you might fall off the end.

```
fwd, bwd :: LZipper a -> Maybe (LZipper a)
fwd (LZipper _ _ []) = Nothing
fwd (LZipper (Reverse xs) e (y:ys)) = Just $ LZipper (Reverse (e:xs)) y ys
bwd (LZipper (Reverse []) _ _) = Nothing
bwd (LZipper (Reverse (x:xs)) e ys) = Just $ LZipper (Reverse xs) x (e:ys)
```

Duplicating a zipper shows you all the ways you could look at it, with the focus on the way you're looking at it currently.

```
instance Comonad LZipper where
    extract (LZipper _ x _) = x
    duplicate z = LZipper (Reverse $ unfoldr (step bwd) z) z (unfoldr (step fwd) z)
        where step move = fmap (\y -> (y, y)) . move
```

For example:

```
ghci> duplicate (mkZipper 'a' "bc")
LZipper (Reverse [])
        (LZipper (Reverse "") 'a' "bc")
        [LZipper (Reverse "a") 'b' "c",LZipper (Reverse "ba") 'c' ""]
-- Abc -> *Abc* aBc abC

ghci> fmap duplicate (fwd $ mkZipper 'a' "bc")
Just (LZipper (Reverse [LZipper (Reverse "") 'a' "bc"])
              (LZipper (Reverse "a") 'b' "c")
              [LZipper (Reverse "ba") 'c' ""])
-- aBc -> Abc *aBc* abC
```

(I'm using capitals and asterisks to indicate the focal point of the zipper.)

---

I'm trying to work with two-dimensional grids with a focus, represented as a zipper of zippers. Each inner zipper is a row of the grid. My end goal is to find paths through a grid by hopping from neighbour to neighbour.

Moving through the grid maintains the invariant that all the rows are focused on the same index. This makes it easy to focus on any of your neighbours.

```
type Grid a = LZipper (LZipper a)

up, down, left, right :: Grid a -> Maybe (Grid a)
up = bwd
down = fwd
left = traverse bwd
right = traverse fwd

extractGrid :: Grid a -> a
extractGrid = extract . extract
mkGrid :: (a, [a]) -> [(a, [a])] -> Grid a
mkGrid (x, xs) xss = mkZipper (mkZipper x xs) $ map (uncurry mkZipper) xss
```

Examples:

```
ghci> let myGrid = mkGrid ('a', "bc") [('d', "ef"), ('g', "hi")]
ghci> myGrid
LZipper (Reverse [])
        (LZipper (Reverse "") 'a' "bc")
        [LZipper (Reverse "") 'd' "ef",LZipper (Reverse "") 'g' "hi"]
-- +-------+ 
-- | A b c |
-- | d e f |
-- | g h i |
-- +-------+

ghci> return myGrid >>= right >>= down
Just (LZipper (Reverse [LZipper (Reverse "a") 'b' "c"])
              (LZipper (Reverse "d") 'e' "f")
              [LZipper (Reverse "g") 'h' "i"])
-- +-------+ 
-- | a b c |
-- | d E f |
-- | g h i |
-- +-------+
```

What I want is the equivalent of `LZipper`'s `duplicate` for grids: a function that takes a grid and produces a grid of all the ways you could look at the grid, with the focus on the *current* way you're looking at it.

```
duplicateGrid :: Grid a -> Grid (Grid a)
```

What I'm expecting:

```
duplicateGrid myGrid
+-------------------------------+
| ********* +-------+ +-------+ |
| * A b c * | a B c | | a b C | |
| * d e f * | d e f | | d e f | |
| * g h i * | g h i | | g h i | |
| ********* +-------+ +-------+ |
| +-------+ +-------+ +-------+ |
| | a b c | | a b c | | a b c | |
| | D e f | | d E f | | d e F | |
| | g h i | | g h i | | g h i | |
| +-------+ +-------+ +-------+ |
| +-------+ +-------+ +-------+ |
| | a b c | | a b c | | a b c | |
| | d e f | | d e f | | d e f | |
| | G h i | | g H i | | g h I | |
| +-------+ +-------+ +-------+ |
+-------------------------------+
```

I tried `duplicateGrid = duplicate . duplicate`. This has the correct type, but (assuming that I interpreted the `show` output correctly, which I probably didn't) it only gives me grids focused somewhere on the first column:

```
(duplicate . duplicate) myGrid
+-------------------------------+
| ********* +-------+ +-------+ |
| * A b c * | a b c | | a b c | |
| * d e f * | D e f | | d e f | |
| * g h i * | g h i | | G h i | |
| ********* +-------+ +-------+ |
| +-------+ +-------+ +-------+ |
| | A b c | | a b c | | a b c | |
| | d e f | | D e f | | d e f | |
| | g h i | | g h i | | G h i | |
| +-------+ +-------+ +-------+ |
| +-------+ +-------+ +-------+ |
| | A b c | | a b c | | a b c | |
| | d e f | | D e f | | d e f | |
| | g h i | | g h i | | G h i | |
| +-------+ +-------+ +-------+ |
+-------------------------------+
```

I also tried `duplicateGrid = duplicate . fmap duplicate`. Assuming once again that I'm capable of interpreting the `show` output, this gave me something that both contained the wrong grids and had the focuses of the rows misaligned, such that moving down would also move you along:

```
(duplicate . fmap duplicate) myGrid
+-------------------------------+
| ********* +-------+ +-------+ |
| * A b c * | D e f | | G h i | |
| * a B c * | d E f | | g H i | |
| * a b C * | d e F | | g h I | |
| ********* +-------+ +-------+ |
| +-------+ ********* +-------+ |
| | A b c | * D e f * | G h i | |
| | a B c | * d E f * | g H i | |
| | a b C | * d e F * | g h I | |
| +-------+ ********* +-------+ |
| +-------+ +-------+ ********* |
| | A b c | | D e f | * G h i * |
| | a B c | | d E f | * g H i * |
| | a b C | | d e F | * g h I * |
| +-------+ +-------+ ********* |
+-------------------------------+
```

This feels like it'd be an easy question for those in the know, but it's making my head spin. I suppose I could hand-crank a function which calls `up`, `down`, `left` and `right`, but I feel like the comonadic machinery ought to be able to do it for me. What is the correct implementation of `duplicateGrid`?

Comment: FYI, you may be interested in other bits. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/25572148/1477667

Comment: And [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12963733/writing-cojoin-or-cobind-for-n-dimensional-grid-type/13100857#13100857) which addresses your question specifically. I somehow missed it, and my answer is rather redundant in its light, but at least I had the opportunity to figure part of it out for myself.

Comment: @AndrásKovács D'oh, my question seems to be an exact duplicate of that one. Don't know why I didn't find it when I was searching. I'll do the right thing and close this one.

Comment: @Benjamin Hodgson, your question is simpler and very well-written. It's easier to understand it and answers to it, so I don't think it should be closed.

Comment: @user3237465 This question and its answers are still here for future generations to search and read. There just won't be any new answers, and there's now a handy link to the duplicated question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a bit of an issue here that we're trying to compose `Grid` with itself, because this setup gives us way too many incorrect ways to implement a `duplicate` with the right type. It's useful to consider the general case where the composed comonads aren't necessarily the same.

Suppose we have `f` and `g` comonads. The type of `duplicate` becomes:

```
duplicate :: f (g a) -> f (g (f (g a)))
```

We can get the following solely using the `Comonad` instances:

```
duplicate . fmap duplicate :: f (g a) -> f (f (g (g a)))
```

From this it becomes apparent that we need to swap `f` and `g` in the middle.

There's a type class called [`Distributive`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/distributive-0.5.0.2/docs/Data-Distributive.html) that has the method we want.

```
class Functor g => Distributive g where
    distribute :: Functor f => f (g a) -> g (f a)
```

In particular, we need to implement `Distributive g`, and then `duplicate` for the composed comonad can be implemented as:

```
duplicate = fmap distribute . duplicate . fmap duplicate
```

However, the documentation in `Distributive` says that values of `g` must have the exact same shape, so we can zip together an arbitrary number of copies without loss of information.

To illustrate this, if `Vec n a` is an `n`-sized vector, then `distribute :: [Vec n a] -> Vec n [a]` is just matrix transposition. It's necessary to pin the down size of the inner vector beforehand, because transposition on a "ragged" matrix must drop some elements, and that's not lawful behavior. Infinite streams and zippers also distribute fine, as they too have just one possible size.

`Zipper` is not a lawful `Distributive` because `Zipper` contains values with differently sized contexts. Still, we can implement improper distribution that supposes uniform context sizes.

Below I'll implement `duplicate` for `Grid` in terms of improper distribution for the underlying lists.

Alternatively, one could just roll up their sleeves and implement a transposition function on `Zipper (Zipper a)` directly. I actually did this, but it gave me a headache and I'm far from being confident that it's correct. It's better to make the types as general as possible, in order to narrow down the space of possible implementations, so there's less room for errors.

I'm going to omit `Reverse` in order to reduce syntactic noise; I hope you excuse me.

```
{-# language DeriveFunctor #-}

import Control.Comonad
import Data.List
import Control.Monad

data Zipper a = Zipper [a] a [a] deriving (Eq, Show, Functor)

lefts, rights :: Zipper a -> [a]
lefts  (Zipper ls _ _) = ls
rights (Zipper _ _ rs) = rs

bwd :: Zipper a -> Maybe (Zipper a)
bwd (Zipper [] _ _) = Nothing
bwd (Zipper (l:ls) a rs) = Just $ Zipper ls l (a:rs)

fwd :: Zipper a -> Maybe (Zipper a)
fwd (Zipper _ _ []) = Nothing
fwd (Zipper ls a (r:rs)) = Just $ Zipper (a:ls) r rs

instance Comonad Zipper where
  extract (Zipper _ a _) = a
  duplicate z =
    Zipper (unfoldr (fmap (join (,)) . bwd) z) z (unfoldr (fmap (join (,)) . fwd) z)
```

We can distribute lists if we know their length beforehand. Since Haskell lists can be infinite, we should measure length with possibly infinite lazy naturals. An alternative solution to measuring length would be using a "guide" list along which we can zip other lists. However, I would rather not assume in the distribution functions that such a dummy list is always available.

```
data Nat = Z | S Nat

length' :: [a] -> Nat
length' = foldr (const S) Z

distList :: Functor f => Nat -> f [a] -> [f a]
distList Z     fas = []
distList (S n) fas = (head <$> fas) : distList n (tail <$> fas)
```

Of course, this fails with runtime exceptions if our length assumption is incorrect.

We can distribute `Zipper`s by distributing their focuses and contexts, provided that we know the lengths of the contexts:

```
distZipper :: Functor f => Nat -> Nat -> f (Zipper a) -> Zipper (f a)
distZipper l r fz = Zipper
  (distList l (lefts <$> fz)) (extract <$> fz) (distList r (rights <$> fz))
```

Finally, we can duplicate `Grid`s in the way we saw before, but first we have to determine the shape of the inner `Zipper`s. Since we assume that all inner `Zipper`s have the same shape, we only look at the `Zipper` in the focus:

```
duplicateGrid :: Grid a -> Grid (Grid a)
duplicateGrid grid@(Zipper _ (Zipper ls _ rs) _) = 
    fmap (distZipper (length' ls) (length' rs)) $ duplicate $ fmap duplicate grid
```

Testing this (as you must have already experienced) is pretty awful, and I haven't yet gotten around to check even a two-by-two case by hand.

Still, I'm fairly confident in the above implementation, since the definitions are highly constrained by the types.

Comment: Why not assume a "dummy list" is available? I believe you get one of those any time you can write a generalized `replicate`, and I don't think what you're doing will make sense outside that context.

Comment: I didn't think much about that, I just tend to reach for the weakest hypotheses, as habit. Now that you point this out, I had to think a bit to come up with convoluted counterexamples. So far I came up with this one: if `f` is a constant functor, then we should be able to `distribute` with any length.  But if the `a` in `f [a]` is bottom, we can only ever produce `[]`  as dummy list (in a total language).

Comment: Your trick of allowing the comonads to differ was illuminating; I wasn't thinking of `Grid` as the _composition_ of `Zipper` with itself (and the corresponding `Comonad` instance). Your solution of duplicating twice and then distributing seems to coincide with [@pigworker's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13100857/1523776), given that if you have access to the stronger `Applicative` and `Traversable` constraints - which we do - then `distribute` is `sequenceA`.

Answer (score 7):

The fundamental problem you're running into is that [zippers don't natively support 2-d structures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8905030/two-dimensional-zipper). The answer there is great (the other answer is basically exactly your definition of `Grid`) and I would encourage you to read it, but the gist is that zippers identify elements with paths to get there and in a 2-d space such an identification is problematic because there are many paths to get to a point.

Hence you'll notice that while your `up` and `down` functions for `Grid`s was completely defined in terms of Zippers, you needed to use `Traversable` machinery to define `left` and `right`. This also means that `left` and `right` don't enjoy the same performance properties as `up` and `down` since you're "going against the grain" so to speak.

Since your `Comonad` instance was defined only using your zipper functions, it can only `duplicate` in the direction that is defined by your zipper, namely `fwd` and `bwd` (and by extension `up` and `down`).

**Edit**: After some more thought I think that your approach is going to be fundamentally problematic. I've preserved my original text below, but there's a more glaring problem.

If you're trying to traverse your zippers as if they were like any 2-d other structure, you're going to keep getting `Nothing` with your `duplicate`. Let's note what happens if you actually try to use your `up, down, left, right` functions on the ostensibly non-problematic `duplicate (mkZipper 'a' "bc")`.

```
*Main> let allRows = duplicate $ mkZipper 'a' "bc"
*Main> down allRows -- This is fine since we're following the zipper normally
Just (LZipper (Backwards [LZipper (Backwards "") 'a' "bc"]) (LZipper (Backwards "a") 'b' "c") [LZipper (Backwards "ba") 'c' ""])
*Main> right allRows
Nothing -- That's bad...
*Main> down allRows >>= right
Nothing -- Still nothing
```

Moving `right` and `left` requires (as you duly note with your mention of the invariant) that every single one of your sub-zippers is homogeneous in structure, otherwise the `traverse` will fail out prematurely. This means that if you actually want to use `left` and `right`, the only way this is going to play nice with `duplicate` is if you use the most uniform `duplicate` possible.

```
duplicate z @ (LZipper left focus right) = 
    LZipper (fmap (const z) left) z (fmap (const z) right)
```

The alternative is to only use the functions that comes with the zipper. That means only using `fwd` and `bwd`, and then `extract`ing the focus and continuing to use `fwd` and `bwd` to get the same thing as `left` and `right`. Of course that means giving up the ability to say both "right then down" and "down then right," but as we've already seen, zippers don't play with multiple paths well.

Now let's double-check your intuitions about how best to interpret what was going on with `duplicate . duplicate $ myGrid`. A nice square isn't really the best way of thinking about what's happening (and you'll see why if you restrict yourself to just `extract` and `fwd` and `bwd`).

```
*Main> let allRows = duplicate . duplicate $ myGrid
*Main> fwd $ extract allRows -- Makes sense
Just ...
-- This *should* be the bottom-left of the grid
*Main> let bottomLeft = extract <$> fwd allRows >>= fwd
*Main> bottomLeft >>= fwd
Nothing -- Nope!
*Main> bottomLeft >>= bwd
Just ... -- Wait a minute...
```

We've actually got a ragged structure.

```
+---------------------------------------------------+
|                     ********* +-------+ +-------+ |
|                     * A b c * | a b c | | a b c | |
|                     * d e f * | D e f | | d e f | |
|                     * g h i * | g h i | | G h i | |
|                     ********* +-------+ +-------+ |
|           +-------+ +-------+ +-------+           |
|           | A b c | | a b c | | a b c |           |
|           | d e f | | D e f | | d e f |           |
|           | g h i | | g h i | | G h i |           |
|           +-------+ +-------+ +-------+           |
| +-------+ +-------+ +-------+                     |
| | A b c | | a b c | | a b c |                     |
| | d e f | | D e f | | d e f |                     |
| | g h i | | g h i | | G h i |                     |
| +-------+ +-------+ +-------+                     |
+---------------------------------------------------+
```

The squares inside of this ragged structure aren't actually squares either, they'll be ragged as well. Equivalently you could think of `fwd` as going diagonally. Or just drop zippers for 2-d structures altogether.

**In my experience, zippers really work best when paired with tree-like things.** I wouldn't be surprised if a Haskell expert could come up with a way of using zippers and all the update / access goodness that comes with them for things like cyclic graphs or even just plain old DAGs, but I can't think of any off the top of my meager head :).

So moral of the story, zippers are quite a bit of a headache for 2-d structures. (Idle thought: maybe lenses might be interesting?)

For the curious, my approach below also only works if you keep in mind the raggedness of the structure we're dealing with; that is `fwd`ing twice and then extracting will get you the equivalent of what OP wants at the bottom-right-hand corner of his grid, not at the bottom left-hand side.

**Original**:

So what you need is some way to switch between your purely zipper-based `duplicate` and your `Traversable`-based duplicate. The easiest way is to take your `duplicate` function you've already written and simply add a `traverse` in the middle.

```
duplicateT :: Traversable t => t (LZipper a) -> LZipper (t (LZipper a))
duplicateT z = LZipper (Backwards $ unfoldr (step bwd) z) z (unfoldr (step fwd) z)
    -- Everything's the exact same except for that extra traverse
    where step move = fmap (\y -> (y, y)) . (traverse move)
```

Now that we have a more general `duplicateT` we can get rid of some nasty code duplication by redefining `duplicate` in your `Comonad` instance to be:

```
-- requires import Data.Functor.Identity
duplicate = fmap runIdentity (duplicate' (Identity z))
```

Then the following gets you what you want

```
duplicateGrid = duplicate . duplicateT
```

Or if you want to switch the order of the columns and rows, you can do the opposite.

Note: It would be even nicer if Haskell let you natively define type constraints on typeclasses so that you could have different instances of Comonad (all mediated with `newtype`s perhaps) for your `LZipper` that change the direction of your `duplicate`. The problem is that you would want something like `instance Comonad LZipper (LZipper a) where ...` or the equivalent `newtype` which you simply can't write in Haskell. You could conceivably do something like [this](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/rmonad-0.8.0.2) with type families, but I suspect that that's probably overkill for this particular instance.

**Edit**: In fact you don't even need `duplicateT` if you give the appropriate `Applicative` instance for `LZipper`.

```
instance Applicative LZipper where
    pure x = LZipper (Backwards (repeat x)) x (repeat x)
    (LZipper leftF f rightF) <*> (LZipper left x right) = LZipper newLeft (f x) newRight
      where
        newLeft = (Backwards (zipWith ($) (forwards leftF) (forwards left)))
        newRight = (zipWith ($) rightF right)
```

Now simply take the original `duplicate` you had before and use `traverse`.

```
duplicateGrid = duplicate . (traverse duplicate)
```

Answer (score 5):

So there's a closely related comonad that may help guide you.  We have:

```
newtype MC m a = MC { unMC :: m -> a }

instance Monoid m => Comonad (MC m) where
    extract (MC f) = f mempty
    duplicate (MC f) = MC (\x -> MC (\y -> f (x <> y)))

instance Functor (MC m) where
    fmap f (MC g) = MC (f . g)
```

So a bidirectionally infinite array would be `MC (Sum Integer) a` and a bidirectionally infinite grid would be `MC (Sum Integer, Sum Integer) a`.  And of course, `MC m (MC n a)` is isomorphic to `MC (m,n) a` via currying.

At any rate, your desired duplicate grid function would be analogous (ignoring newtype wrappers and currying) to:

```
duplicateGrid g x y dx dy = g (x + dx) (y + dy)
```

`duplicate` for the 1D array looks like:

```
duplicate f x y = f (x+y)
```

So `duplicate . duplicate` is:

```
(duplicate . duplicate) f x y z 
    = duplicate (duplicate f) x y z
    = duplicate f (x+y) z
    = f (x + y + z)
```

Not what is wanted.  What does `fmap duplicate` look like:

```
fmap duplicate f x y z = f x (y + z)
```

It's clear doing `duplicate` again will give us the same thing as `duplicate . duplicate` (which it should as this is a comonad law).  Nevertheless, this is a bit more promising.  If we did *two* `fmap`s ...

```
fmap (fmap duplicate) f x y z w
    = fmap duplicate (f x) y z w
    = f x y (z + w)
```

Now if we did `duplicate` we'd get

```
(duplicate . fmap (fmap duplicate)) f x y z w = f (x+y) (z+w)
```

But this is still wrong.  Changing variable names, its `f (x+y) (dx + dy)`.  So we need something to swap the two inner variables...  The category theory name for what we want is a distributive law.  The Haskell name is `Traversable`.  What does `sequenceA` look like for functions (functions form an `Applicative` functor and in fact a `Monad`, the `Reader` monad) look like?  The type says all.

```
sequenceA :: (a -> b -> c) -> (b -> a -> c)
sequenceA f x y = f y x
```

So finally:

```
fmap sequenceA g x y z = g x z y

(duplicate . fmap (fmap duplicate) . fmap sequenceA) g x y dx dy
    = (duplicate . fmap (fmap duplicate)) g x dx y dy
    = g (x + dx) (y + dy)
```

I haven't actually tried the analogous code so I don't know if it works, but math says it should.