# How to combine a comonad and a monad into a comonad?

Tags: scala, haskell, functional-programming, monads, comonad

Assume I have

- a comonad `D`
- a monad `T`
- a distributive law `l : D T -> T D` of the comonad `D` over the monad `T`.

How can I define the comonad `D T`?

Comment: What makes you think that's possible? Let `D` be the identity comonad, then such a scheme would turn any monad into a comonad.

Comment: @Li-yaoXia Because I thought it was the point of having a distributive law. So what is it useful for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't. Suppose `D` is the identity comonad and `T` is `Cont Void`, i.e. the continuation monad at the empty type.

```
newtype D a = D {runD :: a}
newtype T a = T {runT :: (a -> Void) -> Void}
```

Then distributivity holds trivially. But `extract :: D (T a) -> a` is not definable as a total computable program. It would be double negation elimination `forall a. ((a -> Void) -> Void) -> a`, which is not definable in constructive languages.

Comment: Great :-( So what's the point of having a distributive law if you cannot use it to derive a comonad (or a monad)?

Comment: @Bob we need distribution to compose [two comonads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12963733/writing-cojoin-or-cobind-for-n-dimensional-grid-type), for example.