# Create sort of splitfunction haskell

Tags: haskell

I want to split a list on 1 element and take the rest of the list in the second of the tuple and return that.

like this:
*> split [1,2,3,2]
gives
[(1,[2,3,2]),(2,[1,3,2]),(3,[1,2,2]),(2,[1,2,3])]

I tried some code like this but it keeps giving me errors. Can someone help me out with this?

```
split :: [Int] -> [(Int,[Int])]
split [] = []
split (x:xs) = (map (x:) (map snd (split xs))) ++ [(x,[])]
```

Thx!

Comment: 1. Always add the error you encounter. 2. You cannot map `(x:)` onto `[(Int, [Int])]`, since `(Int, [Int])` is not a list. 3. If you only use `xs` in the recursive call, you would always forget the start of the list. 4. Try to be more verbose. Write a function that, for a given index, splits the indexed value and the rest. Use this together with `zipWith [0..]` for a first prototype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [inits](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:inits) and [tails](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:tails) from Data.List:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ParallelListComp #-}
split xs = [(x, pre ++ post) | pre <- inits xs | x:post <- tails xs]
```

or, if you don't like `ParallelListComp`:

```
split xs = [(x, pre ++ post) | (pre, x:post) <- zip (inits xs) (tails xs)]
```

Answer (score 2):

[My answer to an older question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12872133/828361) goes via an answer to this one.

I call this operation `picks` because it tells you all the ways to pick one out of a list (seen as a bag).

```
picks :: [x] -> [(x, [x])]
picks [] = []
picks (x : xs) = (x, xs) : [(y, x : ys) | (y, ys) <- picks xs]
```

It's standard issue zipper-wrangling kit, about which I've written at great length in other answers, such as the one linked above, and [this one, for the works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25572148/828361).

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with a list comprehension. Using `zip` you can create a tuple with an index and each element, then you can consturct a new tuple with your element and the original list minus the element at that index

```
splitter :: [a] -> [(a, [a])]
splitter xs = [(x, removeN n xs) | (n, x) <- zip [0..] xs]
```

That's using a function to remove the nth element

```
removeN :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
removeN n xs = take n xs ++ drop (n + 1) xs
```

example

```
*Main> splitter [1..4]
[(1,[2,3,4]),(2,[1,3,4]),(3,[1,2,4]),(4,[1,2,3])]
```

Comment: nice but this has quadratic complexity because of take/drop on each iteration

Comment: @maxtaldykin, that actually can't be avoided. The "pre-hole" parts of the result lists can't share any structure with each other.

Comment: However, using `splitAt` should give better constant factors.